# Input field, move text that is being input

Tags: css, input, placeholder

To make room for an icon, I have moved the placeholder text `35px` to the right of my `input`; However, when I start to type in the `input` field, the text starts behind the icon.

I attempted a bit of googling, but i have yet to find an answer. The search results I've seen regard the placeholder, but it is not what I am having troubles with.

How do I move the text which is being inputted, so it matches that of the placeholder? (`form-group__input`)

```css
.login {
  background-color: $color-white;
  width: 30vw;
  position: absolute;
  @include position-center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.login h2 {
  color: $color-gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.login .form-group {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.login .form-group .form-group__input {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login .form-group .form-group__input::placeholder {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.login .form-group__icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: gray;
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="login">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" placeholder="someemail@email.com" class="form-group__input">
    <span class="form-group__icon"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="**********" class="form-group__input">
    <span class="form-group__icon"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
  </div>
  <a href="Index.html" class="btn btn--blue">Log In</a>
  <a href="CreateAccount.html" class="btn btn--simple">Create Account</a>
</section>
```

Comment: why not set a padding-left straight to the input?

Comment: @fcalderan i have no idea... because i did not think about it haha ^^ ...

Comment: actually @andrelange91 what were you actually asking for here? the matching of the input text and placeholder is one thing, but you referenced to the text starting behind the icon being an issue.  did you mean to hide the icon as well?

Comment: @BrettCaswell i moved the placeholder, but then when i entered text, the text started behind the icon, instead of in the same place as the placeholder text. But just moving the padding-left to the input instead of the placeholder fixed it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz try this code..

**css**

```
.form-group__input {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
}
```

Comment: Bcoz In large screen like above 1920 window size, its seems close to the icon.. so that we can add the additional 5px space for clear visual.

Comment: I'm going to remove my previous comments.. I didn't mean for this to become a discussion or cause confusion.  simply: @andrelange91 use the padding from this answer, remove the `padding-left` on your `::placeholder` then it will align.